# managing grouped buttons loading state within a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two buttons accept and reject buttons, that are part of a card which is generated from a map function.
I need to enable each of the cards states and set to loading independently.
This is how I am currently activating the state to busy:

```
    const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState({});

........

setBusy(prev => ({ ...prev, [id]: true }));
        setTimeout(
            () => setBusy(prev => ({ ...prev, [id]: false })),
            3000
        );
```

These are the buttons

```
return [
            <Button loading={isBusy[id] || false} title="Invite" onPress={() => invite(id)}  />,
            <Button loading={isBusy[id] || false} title="Remove" onPress={() => reject(id)}  />,
        ];
```

The challenge at the moment, is clicking on Invite button activates also the state of remove button in that particular card that matches the `id`.
This is all contained in a card displayed under a map function, each card has two buttons to be displayed, invite and reject button respectively, I need to handle the sate of these individual buttons within each card separately, so that if I click invite, `isBusy` is activated only for invite button and reject button is handled as separate too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, you need to have two separate states for every card and one for each button.  you can change the keys to `${id}-invite` and `${id}-remove` or merge them into an object with id key.

```
const [isInviting, setInviting] = useState(true);
const [isRemoving, setRemoving] = useState(true);
```

then create two separate setter functions to do the job you want, and use each one in corresponding button.

Comment: @Rabbani yes yes yes, you have understood my query. could you have an example of both scenarios?

Comment: I tried to add the main idea. try implementing and testing it.

Comment: ooh, I seee, this works well. Thanks alot.
quick question, is this the optimal method to use, or there could be an alternative?

Comment: for the optimal method, it's better to see the whole component and logic. don't forget to accept the answer as the correct one if it helped.